# Refactoring a COALESCE comparison

Tags: sql, t-sql, sqlperformance

In the `OR` section of a `WHERE` clause I have something like this:

```
COALESCE(Table2.FireDate, Table1.HireDate,'06/06/2079') = ISNULL(Table3.DeathDate,'06/06/2079')
```

I wanted to see is there a way to avoid `COALESCE` call and still achieve the same result? My hope is gaining some performance if possible.

Comment: To possibly really gain performance here, rather think of introducing computed columns for the expressions in the table, indexing them and using them in the query instead of the expressions themselves.

Comment: @stickybit  but the values are from three different tables... Still can use computed column?

Comment: Touchée, I didn't realise that o_O... but you could at least include `ISNULL(Table3.DeathDate,'06/06/2079')` in an index and maybe including `ISNULL(Table1.HireDate,'06/06/2079')` (in another index and rewriting the `COALESE`s to nested `ISNULL`s) might help as well. Depending on the rest of the query.

Comment: @stickybit hmm that's an interesting idea, I will play with it.

Comment: Any chance for the full SQL?

Comment: @UnhandledExcepSean   no, its company code and too big for me to morph it into a more generic style to post.

Comment: So, logically, this is an OR. I've personally found that it is better performance to have two or move queries that produce each part of the OR and union the results together. Another idea would be to  have a sub-query produce the recordset with those fields and then filter outside that level; that *might* produce a faster result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't sure that performance will be better. But you can get rid from coalesce as you want:

```
declare @fireDate date = null -- '01/20/2017'
declare @hireDate date = '01/20/2017'
declare @deathDate date = '01/20/2017'

if (COALESCE(@fireDate, @hireDate, '06/06/2079') = ISNULL(@deathDate, '06/06/2079'))
begin
    select '+'
end;


if(@fireDate is null and @hireDate is null and @deathDate is null)
   or (@fireDate = @deathDate)
   or (@fireDate is null and @hireDate = @deathDate) begin
    select '+'
end;
```

Comment: Question: What happened to '06/06/2079' ?

Comment: oh I see, looks like we won't need it in the new logic

Comment: What happened to `Table1`?  I'm baffled as to why this was accepted.

Comment: @ hireDate = Table1.HireDate, 
@ fireDate = Table2.FireDate, 
@ deathDate = Table3.DeathDate. 
  We just unwrapped conditions.